# Sklearn AdaBoostClassifier errors out on same data as GradientBoostingClassifier

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm testing out a suite of classifiers on some simple churn data. Columns are cost of the plan, count of an event, and then a sparse one hot encoding of the country (Other, US, Unknown)

```
    $       Count   Other   US  Unknown
0   13.99   0       0       0   1
1   13.99   391     0       0   1
2   35.00   2       0       1   0
3   13.99   0       0       0   1
4   13.99   0       0       0   1
```

Feeding this data into my code works fine for the Gradient Boosting classifier:

```
estimator = GradientBoostingClassifier()
param = {"estimator__loss": ["deviance"],
       "estimator__n_estimators": [10, 50, 100],
       "estimator__max_depth": [2, 3, 4, 5],
       "estimator__max_features": ["auto","log2"]}
selector = RFECV(estimator, step=1, cv=3, scoring="roc_auc")
clf = grid_search.GridSearchCV(selector, param, cv=3, n_jobs=-1)
clf.fit(X,y)
print clf.best_estimator_.estimator_
print np.mean(clf.best_estimator_.grid_scores_)
print clf.best_estimator_.ranking_
print("Took %.2f seconds" % (time() - start))
```

However if I run the same code with the AdaBoost classifier:

```
start = time()
estimator = AdaBoostClassifier(DecisionTreeClassifier())
param = {"estimator__n_estimators": [10, 50, 100]}
selector = RFECV(estimator, step=1, cv=3, scoring="roc_auc")
clf = grid_search.GridSearchCV(selector, param, cv=3, n_jobs=-1)
clf.fit(X,y)
print clf.best_estimator_.estimator_
print np.mean(clf.best_estimator_.grid_scores_)
print clf.best_estimator_.ranking_
print("Took %.2f seconds" % (time() - start))
```

I get ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64'). I checked for NaN and infinity using:

```
print np.isnan(X).any() #False
print np.isfinite(X).any() #True
```

I also checked the documentation for the AdaBoostClassifier to see if any of my input values where too large; the largest value is just under 4000 in the Count column. I'm not certain what my next steps should be to resolve this error; any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Validate your input vectors (both the features and labels). What are their dtypes? Were strings or other values introduced by accident?

Comment: @RandyOlson the features are float64 and the labels are int64. Checked the inputs for strings or other values but couldn't find them.